# How to make transparent background or switch header in stack navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using stack navigation with custom header like photo below.
I wanted to make the search screen content transparent to see the previous screen or switch the header. any idea how can i do that ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understand wrong, you need to add

```
navigationOptions: {
    headerTransparent: {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      zIndex: 100,
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0
    }
```